# To prove that $B\subset A\rightarrow A=A\cup B$ is it necessary to consider the cases $A\cup B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B\neq \emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For what I know, to prove $B\subset A\rightarrow A=A\cup B$ it suffices to prove that $A\subset (A\cup B)$ and $(A\cup B)\subset A$.

Prove that $A\subset (A\cup B)$ is trivial, because $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A\vee x\in B\}$.

My teacher in proving that $(A\cup B)\subset A$ separated the proof into two parts: $A\cup B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B\neq \emptyset$. But I didn't understand why the need to separate this proof in two cases since

$x\in (A\cup B)\to x\in A \vee x\in B$

We know, by hypothesis, that $B\subset A$, so we can conclude that $(x\in A\vee x\in B)\leftrightarrow(x\in A)$ is tautology(using truth table). So saying $x\in A\vee x\in B$ is equivalent to saying $x\in A$ which implies

$x\in (A\cup B)\to x\in A \vee x\in B\equiv x\in A\Rightarrow (A\cup B)\subset A$ (note: the implication $p\to q$ is true whenever $p$ is false).

In my opinion in the proof that $(A\cup B)\subset A$ there was no need to consider two cases, but as my teacher has great knowledge about set theory I feel that I am making a mistake by not considering the two cases. That is why I ask for help in this doubt.

**Obs.:** If I used some logical symbol wrongly let me know, please, since I still know few things about propositional logic.

Comment: You're right. No need for dividing into empty/nonempty cases. Perhaps your teacher was just illustrating some other point, maybe about vacuous truths?

Comment: I see no flaw in your reasoning.  Do keep in mind that teachers sometimes do unnecessary things in class to emphasize a point or a technique.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Later I'll ask my teacher why he did it. He was separating in cases all the problems similar to that. Because of this I ended up getting confused.

Comment: The two cases to use are x in A and x in B.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The reason you feel there is no reason to consider the two cases is because you feel that one case is trivial.   Indeed the conclusion from those premises is *a vacuuously truth*:

$$\begin{array}{lrcl}\because&(B\subseteq A)~,~ (A\cup B=\emptyset) &\vdash& \forall x ~\big((x\in A\cup B) \to (x\in A)\big)\\\hline\therefore&(B\subseteq A)~,~ (A\cup B=\emptyset)&\vdash&(A\cup B\subseteq A)\end{array}$$

---

However, not all proofs will have a trivial result from the empty case; for instance any proof involving an existance claim *may well* lead to an exception.   Your teacher just wants you to get into the habit of verifying a proof does not fail in the empty case.

Comment: if $A\cup B=\varnothing$ and $B \subset A$ does it mean $A=\{\varnothing\}$??

Comment: No, but $A\cup B=\varnothing$ and $B\subseteq A$ does mean $A=\varnothing$.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: "The reason you feel there is no reason to consider the two cases is because you feel that one case is trivial." The OP does not omit one case from their argument, claiming it to be trivial; instead they provide a single argument which prove the statement regardless of whether $A\cup B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Stu. $\{\emptyset\}$ is $not$ the empty set. It has one member:  $\emptyset$ is its member.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, and I see no errors. We can also observe that  $A\subset B\iff \forall x\;(x\in B\implies x\in A).$ Therefore if $B\subset A$ then for all $x$ we have  $$x\in A\cup B)\implies  (x\in A\lor x\in B)\implies$$ $$\implies (x\in A\lor x\in A)\implies(x\in A)\implies$$ $$\implies(x\in A \lor x\in B)\implies(x\in A\cup B).$$

From this we infer that for all $x$ we have $x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A$.

This is in my style, which is almost never brief.